# List all processes?

Tags: java, windows, process, jna

How is it possible to get a list of all running processes in Java using JNA 4.5.0?

I already tried this code:

```
WinNT winNT = (WinNT) Native.loadLibrary(WinNT.class, W32APIOptions.UNICODE_OPTIONS);
winNT.HANDLE snapshot = winNT.CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(Tlhelp32.TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, new WinDef.DWORD(0));
Thelp32.PROCESSENTRY32.ByReference processEntry = new Tlhelp32.PROCESSENTRY32.ByReference();

while (winNT.Process32Next(snapshot, processEntry)) {
    System.out.println(processEntry.th32ProcessID + "\t" + Native.toString(processEntry.szExeFile));
}
winNT.CloseHandle(snapshot);
```

but it isn't working because it is written for an older version of the JNA lib.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the functions you are looking for nowadays exist in the `Kernel32` class. With some small corrections, your snippet works just fine:

```
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Kernel32;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Tlhelp32;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinNT;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Kernel32 kernel = Kernel32.INSTANCE;

        WinNT.HANDLE snapshot = kernel.CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(Tlhelp32.TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, new WinDef.DWORD(0));
        Tlhelp32.PROCESSENTRY32.ByReference processEntry = new Tlhelp32.PROCESSENTRY32.ByReference();

        while (kernel.Process32Next(snapshot, processEntry)) {
            System.out.println(processEntry.th32ProcessID + "\t" + Native.toString(processEntry.szExeFile));
        }
        kernel.CloseHandle(snapshot);
    }
}
```